# Call method on object itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am trying to create method that will configure UILable for various different properties. I want to use the same method for doing same configuration for some other UILable as well. As of now my code looks like following.

```
-(UILabel *) setUpLabel:(UILabel *)label {
/* Label configuration code*/
}
```

I call this code as following

```
{...
    UILabel *lbl = [UILabel alloc] init];
    lbl = [self setUpLabel:lbl];
...}
```

I was wondering if it can be done in better way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't need to return a UILabel, the manipulation you do to that instance of UILabel will persist back to the caller

Comment: Kevin is right. Simply pass the label you want configured as a parameter to your `setUpLabel:` method and the configuration will take place on the label that you passed to it.

Comment: Personally, I would leave the return val, but but remove the passed parameter and move the alloc/init into the `setUpLabel` method. That way, you can condense a label declaration into a single line `UILabel *lbl = [self setUpLabel];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse it for multiple label in the same view controller, this is a fine way of doing it.

If you want to share that method across different view controllers, a common way to do it is to create a "Theme" singleton object that contains these methods. Or you could add the method to a category on `UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Sumit, your code is a bit strange. You can either follow the factory pattern to create the label or you could pass the label you want by reference to do the configuration. You are doing a hybrid of both...

Factory:

```
-(UILabel *) setUpLabel:(NSDictionary *)config {
    /* Label configuration code*/
}

UILabel *myLabel = [self setupLabel:config];
```

pass by reference:

```
-(void) setUpLabel:(UILabel *)label {
/* Label configuration code*/
}

UILabel *lbl = [UILabel alloc] init];
[self setUpLabel:lbl];
```

I would recommend the second in this case